# Regex: Find strings without character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

i build regex expression that matches 
2 letters or 2 letters folowed by '/' and next 2 letters for example:

```
rt bl/ws se gn/wd wk bl/rt

/^(((\s+)?[a-zA-Z]{2}(\/[a-zA-Z]{2})?)(\s+|$))+$/i
```

and that works without problems.
Next problem what I have is match all "word" not containing '/' character.
and replace all matches by duplicate values separated by '/'. For above example excepted output should be:

```
rt/rt bl/ws se/se gn/wd wk/wk bl/rt
```

I tried it some time but without success. Could you help me with that ?

**Update 1:**

I've started with regex that matches words not containing 'at'

```
(\b((?!(at))\w)+\b)
```

Et the and I want to replace matched elements with python like

```
re.sub(r'(\b((?!(at))\w)+\b)', r'\1/\1', text)
```

but first have to find right elements ...

Comment: Show us what you tried, it will help identify your problem.

Comment: Also, it would be great if you mentioned the programming language you are using the regex in.

Comment: Your regex is very complicated. You could simplify it. For instance, `(\s+)?` is the same as `\s*`. Also have a look at `\w` and `\b`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew OP never excepts that work will be made by someone else. Is there ask for help not right place on this forum ?

Comment: Then you may use `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[^\W\d_]+(?!\S)', r'\g<0>/\g<0>', s)`. Or `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)([^\W\d_]+)(?!\S)', r'\1/\1', s)`. To exclude `at` word matches, use `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(?!at(?!\S))([^\W\d_]+)(?!\S)', r'\1/\1', s)`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a flavour of regex that supports negative lookbehind this regex should find the strings you want to replace:

`(?<!\/)([A-Za-z]{2}(?!\/))`

`(?<!\/)` - makes sure there isn't a `/` behind the match
   `([A-Za-z]{2}` looks for two alphabetic characters
   `(?!\/))` makes sure there isn't a trailing `/`

In Python you would use it like this:

```
print(re.sub(r'(?<!\/)([A-Za-z]{2}(?!\/))',r'\1/\1','rt bl/ws se gn/wd wk bl/rt'))
```

Output:

```
rt/rt bl/ws se/se gn/wd wk/wk bl/rt
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/MICNA3130)

In PHP you would use it like so:

```
$str = 'rt bl/ws se gn/wd wk bl/rt';
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\/)([A-Za-z]{2}(?!\/))/', '$1/$1', $str);
```

Output:

```
rt/rt bl/ws se/se gn/wd wk/wk bl/rt
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/A4ner)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let string = 'rt bl/ws se gn/wd wk bl/rt'

console.log(string.replace(/(?:(?<=^)|(?<= ))(\w+)(?= |$)/gi, '$1/$1'))
```